# C# populate string multidimensiona array inside a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, matrix, unity-game-engine

im trying to create a matrix and populate it with strings so i can manipulate it later, heres my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScenarioMatrix : MonoBehaviour {

    public GFRectGrid _grid;
    public string[,] _scenarioArray;
    /*
    USAREMOS A SEGUINTE NOMECLATURA PARA O GRID
    E = GRID VAZIO TEM SOMENTE O CENARIO
    SP = Spawn Point, é onde o player começa
    EP = é onde o player termina
    L = Lajota é o caminho onde o player pode andar
    CG = color get, é onde o bloco pega uma cor
    CD = color drop é onde o bloco deixa a cor
    */
    private string[] _values = {"E","SP","EP","L","CG","CD" };

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {

        _scenarioArray = new string[(int)_grid.size.x, (int)_grid.size.z];

        //montamos o array
        for (int _largura = 1; _largura <= _grid.size.x; _largura++)
        {
            for (int _comprimento = 1; _comprimento <= _grid.size.z; _comprimento++)
            {
                string _valor = _values[Random.Range(0, _values.Length-1)];
                _scenarioArray[_largura, _comprimento] = _valor;
                //Debug.Log(_values[Random.Range(0, _values.Length)]);
            }

        }
        Debug.Log(_scenarioArray);
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

So far im getting the error
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
ScenarioMatrix.Start () (at Assets/Game/Scripts/ScenarioMatrix.cs:30)

what can i be doing wrong in this code?

Comment: what is your `(int)_grid.size.x, (int)_grid.size.z` sizes?

Comment: the site is 5x5 usualy but can change, and should change

Comment: change  `for (int _largura = 0; _largura < _grid.size.x; _largura++)` and  `for (int _comprimento = 1; _comprimento < _grid.size.z; _comprimento++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `_comprimento <= _grid.size.z` with `_comprimento < _grid.size.z`

and

`_largura <= _grid.size.x` with `_largura < _grid.size.x`

**Arrays index are 0 based (They start from 0, not 1)**

Comment: worked the error is fixed how can i debug.log this matrix to see it?

Comment: just do `//Debug.Log(_valor);` in the inner for loop, Just after `_scenarioArray[_largura, _comprimento] = _valor;`

Comment: you should also start the loop with index 0. `int _largura = 0` and `int _comprimento = 0;`